# How can I get bazel to ignore a directory without setting global .bazelignore?

Tags: bazel

My repo has some gitignored paths that are sometimes populated during non-Bazel development and contain symlinks to other code paths that can sometimes cause the Bazel loader to too aggressively look for packages, which can cause `bazel query` to wrongly match packages through symlinks. Workspace root `.bazelignore` allows me to hide these directories but is there an option to tell Bazel to ignore a directory using a more local config rather than a single global file?

Specifically, I'm using [Yarn Workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces) in Node.js. The source tree looks like the following:

```
BUILD
package.json
yarn.lock
myapp
├─ BUILD
└─ package.json
```

Running `yarn install` outside of Bazel creates a directory called `node_modules`, which includes third-party dependencies as well as a symlink farm to local packages:

```
BUILD
package.json
yarn.lock
node_modules
├─ myapp -> ../myapp
└─ some_3p_dep
myapp
├─ BUILD
└─ package.json
```

Expressing this pattern through Bazel is straightforward, and I've written a custom rule that just uses `ctx.actions.declare_directory` to create `node_modules` in the bindir (I have to tar/untar the symlink to conceal it from Bazel to prevent it from complaining, but the rule works great).

However, this results in a problem if a user runs the `yarn install` command locally without Bazel then runs something like `bazel query //... | xargs bazel test` to run all tests. In general `bazel query //...` appears to wrongly list not just targets in `//myapp` but also targets in `//node_modules/myapp`... after all `node_modules/myapp/BUILD` technically exists. This is problematic at the very least because it duplicates targets, but also in practice it causes `ArtifactPrefixConflictException` for any outputs that `//node_modules/myapp` declares because the paths overlap with the `//:node_modules` target/output. If I wanted to, I could technically work around the latter by messing with output names, but the duplication would still exist, wasting compute time and leading to different Bazel results depending on if the user is also doing a non-Bazel devloop.

`.bazelignore` appears to work fine to get Bazel not to traverse `node_modules`, but it only supports full paths (https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8106) and requires every new `node_modules` that may come into existence, which is cumbersome because it's a global file. Is there an option that we can declare the ignore more globally or another workaround I'm missing?